# Creating multiple resized images in codeigniter?

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I was trying to upload an image and create multiple resized copies of that image to be used in different locations in a website. I was using the CodeIgniter Image Manipulation Class and it worked perfectly and I was able to get a resized image, however when I tried to create more than one resized image it didn’t work.

```
//controller
<?php
class Upload extends CI_Controller{
    public function upload_image(){
        $this->upload_model->do_upload(); //execute the upload function
    }
}

//model
<?php
class User_model extends CI_Model{
  var $original_path;
  var $resized_path;
  var $thumbs_path;

  //initialize the path where you want to save your images
  function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    //return the full path of the directory
    //make sure these directories have read and write permessions
    $this->original_path = realpath(APPPATH.'../uploads/original');
    $this->resized_path = realpath(APPPATH.'../uploads/resized');
    $this->thumbs_path = realpath(APPPATH.'../uploads/thumbs');
  }

  function do_upload(){
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $config = array(
    'allowed_types'     => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png', //only accept these file types
    'max_size'          => 2048, //2MB max
    'upload_path'       => $this->original_path //upload directory
  );



       $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $image_data = $this->upload->data(); //upload the image

        // desired config for the resize() function
        $config = array(
        'source_image'      => $image_data['full_path'], //path to the uploaded image
        'new_image'         => $this->resized_path, //path to
        'maintain_ratio'    => true,
        'width'             => 128,
        'height'            => 128
        );
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
```

Comment: You can also try [Wideimage library](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i am using CI Image manipulation Class, I thought that calling the resize function twice will produce two resized images but that didn’t actually work and after  some research and tutorials I found out that I have to initialize the image_lib class every time I call the resize() function.

So Your function should look like this

```
function do_upload(){
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $config = array(
    'allowed_types'     => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png', //only accept these file types
    'max_size'          => 2048, //2MB max
    'upload_path'       => $this->original_path //upload directory
  );

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $image_data = $this->upload->data(); //upload the image

    //your desired config for the resize() function
    $config = array(
    'source_image'      => $image_data['full_path'], //path to the uploaded image
    'new_image'         => $this->resized_path, //path to
    'maintain_ratio'    => true,
    'width'             => 128,
    'height'            => 128
    );


    //you have to call the initialize() function each time you call the resize()
    //otherwise it will not work and only generate one thumbnail
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();

    desires $config array 
    //here is the second thumbnail, notice the call for the initialize() function again
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
  }
}
```